# How to do a mixed model with 4 factors?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am curious how I can perform a mixed model with 4 factors and 1 continuous variable.

```
lmer(Scores ~ 1 + (1 | Test) + (1 | Sex) + (1 | Age) + (1 | Status), df)
```

I have a bunch of test scores (Scores), a few different tests (Tests), Sex, Age, and then Status, such as whether they are married or not. How can i model this so that I can tell how Test performance ( or scores), is associated with Age. Am i using the right package even?

Comment: Those don't look like they should be random effects, to me. If you provide more detail someone might be able to help - what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

Mixed-effects models are used to account for correlations in the outcome variable within the same level of a grouping variable. For example, in a multi-center study to account for correlations of participants from the same study group, or in a longitudinal study to account for the correlations in the repeated measurements of each participant.

There is not sufficient information in your question, but I would expect that you need to include these variables as random effects in your model. Rather as fixed effects. Perhaps `Test` could be a grouping variable, with scores coming from the same test being correlated.